# How to display db value to text box using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am new to vb.net.
I want to display some values into a text box.

Given below is my code.
But it's not showing any value.

I want to display the academic year into yearTextBox.
Help me to find a solution.

Code :

```
con1.Open()
cmd1 = con1.CreateCommand
Dim y As String = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(TextBox1.Text) // getting current year (eg: y=2015)
cmd1.CommandText = "select ACADEMIC_YEAR from ACADEMIC_YEAR where CURRENT_YEAR='" & "y" & "'"
sdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader
If sdr1.Read Then
yearTextBox.Text = sdr1(0)
End If
sdr1.Close()
```

demo table:

```
ACADEMIC_YEAR    CURRENT_YEAR
-------------     -----------
2014-2015            2015
```

Comment: I'd bet that there is something wrong with the SQL statement. How about providing the database layout that you are using? Does this code really compile and run without throwing exceptions?

Comment: What do you expect in variable 'y' ? And what will be the example value in TextBox1.text ?

Comment: First of all, remove the quotes around y.

Comment: Your definition of `y` makes no sense.